# LinkedIn API throttle

Tags: linkedin-api

Before I start, let me tell you that I'm aware that this question could look as a duplicate, but https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits page is not accessible anymore...

I got stuck with the `w_messages` API. Some of the responses throw me a "Throttle limit for calls to this resource is reached.".

I do understand that this is a necessary functionality, but I must find something to avoid reaching it.

My problem is, as the documentation is not accessible anymore, I don't know the kind of limit I've reached : daily limit, user limit, application limit, ..?

I need help understanding that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation was moved to https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits and will remain available to LinkedIn partner developers after May 12th, 2015 when public access to that API will no longer be available.

Comment: Wait... You are telling me that the API will not be available after may 2015..?

Comment: Correct.  More details here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes